# BOLT won't render the HTML?

Tags: html, bolt-cms

I am inputting following HTML in BOLT's wsywig editor:

```
<p>Build <strong>PROFITABLE PRODUCTS</strong> through</p>
```

What get rendered is also:

```
<p>Build <strong>PROFITABLE PRODUCTS</strong> through</p>
```

What I was expecting is:

Build **PROFITABLE PRODUCTS** through

I have checked Config.yml file as well to check if there exists any HTML option but no luck.

Comment: Does the WYSIWYG editor have a switch for "source" or "raw" or "html" or some such.

Comment: The name of the CMS sounds familiar, by the way. Was it written by someone we know?

Comment: I had to use `{{ markdown(record.values.html) }}` to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you typed this into the normal wysisyg view or in the code view? There is a button on the editor to switch to the source code view where you can insert your HTML directly.